# Can I remove an xml file from browser memory?

Tags: javascript, xml, browser, xhtml

I am working on a javascript web app. It progresses through "pages" and loads an xml file for each page. Is there a way to remove an xml file from memory?

Or do I even need to? Is having say 20 xml files in memory bad?

Comment: Unless you have security restrictions that justifies unloading these files I don't think you need to. Another reason to remove them is if they are really big files (several MB). Then, I guess you would need to create a browser extension to access this function (Firefox AddOns, IE plugins, Chrome extension...)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really give enough details about your problem, so I will assume that you mean you have XML files as strings in memory. In that case, you can use the `delete` keyword for that.

However, according to the Mozilla Developer documentation, "You can use the delete operator to delete variables declared implicitly but not those declared with the var statement."

This means you'll have to add properties to the window object itself instead:

```
> var a = "Lorem...";
undefined
> delete a;
false
> a;
"Lorem..."
> window.b = "Lorem...";
"Lorem..."
> delete window.b;
true
> b
ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

Another way to write this is to declare variables implicitly, without the var keyword. This also works:

```
> c = "Lorem...";
"Lorem..."
> delete c;
true
```

Since JavaScript is garbage collected, when these become unreferenced they are cleared from memory automatically.